# WooCommerce get parent category from current category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I get the parent category from a sub category page in WooCommerce? After doing extensive research this piece of code looks promising

```
get_ancestors( $product_cat_id, 'product_cat' );
```

but it keeps returning 'array' in a loop.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$parentcats = get_ancestors($product_cat_id, 'product_cat');
```

This is the correct way and you will get one or more parent categories, as an array and loop over it to get  the value like below:

```
foreach($parentcats as $parentcat){
    echo $parentcat;
}
```

Comment: Excellent stuff. I used this to get current id :  $cate = get_queried_object();  $cateID = $cate->term_id; And it worked perfectly fine. Thank you.